# Match characters that are not inside certain HTML tag and does not contain a certain word

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a PHP regex that do the following : 
(1) Get text inside `<p>` tags that (2) DOES NOT contain the word "x x x" and (3) NOT nested inside a `<blockquote>`

Example :

```
<p>This is one</p> //true
<p>This is one x x x</p> //false, has "x x x"
<blockquote><i>something</i><p>This is one</p></blockquote> //false, nested inside blockquote
```

Comment: Do not parse the HTML with regex :)

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are a good solution for this. What language are you working in? A parsing library would be a much better approach.

Comment: @Jonny5 : I'm using PHP

Comment: @VMAtm : It's probably not the best practice but I need it for a quick fix.

Comment: Will there be nested `<p>` elements? Will there be nested `<blockquote>` elements? A regular expression would be fine to match (or not-match) strings containing "x x x", but it would be much better to use an HTML parser to filter out the tag requirements.

Comment: There might be nested `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression is the incorrect tool for this job.  Even if it's just for a "quick fix", it's still not the correct tool.

The tool I like to use here is called XPath.  Using PHP's DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes, we can find the value(s) you want.

I took your HTML, then searched for `<p>` tags that matched your criteria.

```
<?php
$html = <<<END
<p>This is one</p>
<p>This is one x x x</p>
<blockquote><i>something</i><p>This is one</p></blockquote>
END;

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

$p = $xPath->query('//p[not(contains(text(), "x x x")) and not(ancestor::blockquote)]');

foreach($p as $e){
    echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/238099

<sub>Edit: Updated answer with a better XPath query to work with nested tags.</sub>